# How to convert an array to a hash with array elements as hash keys and all hash values all set to given value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Using Ruby 2.1 (with ActiveSupport 3.x, if that helps), I want to convert an array like this:

```
[ :apples, :bananas, :strawberries ]
```

Into a hash like this:

```
{ :apples => 20, :bananas => 20, :strawberries => 20 }
```

Technically, this works:

```
array = [ :apples, :bananas, :strawberries ]
hash = Hash[array.zip(Array.new(array.length, 20))]
# => {:apples=>20, :bananas=>20, :strawberries=>20}
```

But that seems really clunky, and I feel like there's a more straightforward way to do this. Is there one?

I looked at [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) as well as the *default value* option for [Hash#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) but didn't see anything providing a simple method for this conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer:

```
ary = [ :apples, :bananas, :strawberries ]
Hash[[*ary.each_with_object(20)]]
# => {:apples=>20, :bananas=>20, :strawberries=>20}
```

Alternatively (as pointed out by the OP):

```
ary.each_with_object(20).to_h
# => {:apples=>20, :bananas=>20, :strawberries=>20}
```

Basically, calling `each_with_object` returns an `Enumerator` object of pairs consisting of each value and the number 20 (i.e. `[:apples, 20], ...`) which can subsequently be converted to a hash.

Comment: Just copied from my vim `array = [ :apples, :bananas, :strawberries ]
Hash[array.each_with_object(20).to_a]
# => {:apples=>20, :bananas=>20, :strawberries=>20}`.. But you are done.. +1

Comment: One suggestion, you may or may not agree. `*` is not much readable here for me... only :) I use always `to_a`.

Comment: In Ruby 2.1 at least, I just discovered this works: `array.each_with_object(20).to_h` -- if you update your answer to this, I will accept it, as that's the solution I've decided to go for (and your answer inspired this attempt).

Comment: @BenLee all other answers also work with `#to_h`.. This method a cute one.. It has been introduced since 2.1 only.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, thanks for that tip (and sorry I can't give a checkmark to all three answers -- if I could I would, as they are all nice methods).

Comment: @BenLee No issue.. Enjoy Ruby.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Hash[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
Hash[array.map { |f| [f, 20] }]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product) will be helpful here :

```
ary = [ :apples, :bananas, :strawberries ]
Hash[ary.product([20])]
# => {:apples=>20, :bananas=>20, :strawberries=>20}
```